# Find traversal path in target sets

Tags: python, algorithm, traversal, state-machine

I have a traversal problem, and I have tried some way to find the best traversal in my problem.

The question is, I have some sets and each element has it weight. 
Let list below..

```
('f12', 'f10', 'f15')
('f07', 'f05', 'f01', 'f15')
('f08', 'f05', 'f21')
('f07', 'f19', 'f15')
('f21', 'f10', 'f15')
('f07', 'f04', 'f01')
('f06', 'f07', 'f01', 'f15')
('f05', 'f04', 'f10', 'f15')
('f05', 'f21', 'f19', 'f15')
('f07', 'f02', 'f15')
('f07', 'f21', 'f01')
('f07', 'f21', 'f15')
('f18', 'f05', 'f01', 'f15')
('f07', 'f05', 'f21')
('f07', 'f12', 'f15')
('f05', 'f01', 'f17', 'f15')
('f08', 'f12', 'f15')
('f04', 'f01', 'f12')
('f10', 'f16', 'f17')
('f04', 'f21', 'f15')
('f07', 'f18', 'f15')
('f07', 'f16', 'f15')
('f07', 'f03', 'f15')
('f21', 'f03', 'f15')
('f03', 'f12', 'f15')
('f06', 'f10', 'f16', 'f15')
.....
```

And each fXX has relatively weight called w1~w21
I want to find a best traversal path with f1~f21(Or the shortest).
And If I have traverse one of these sets, then I can stop.

For example.. If I traverse f01->f02->f04->f07 then stop since the

```
('f07', 'f04', 'f01')
```

has been discovered.

**Idea**

- I have been thought about FSM(finite state machine), but I don't know how to do it with weight?

**Question**

How can I build this kind of problem into some FSM or some way to get the traversal path?
It should has a enter element? Right?

**Note**

Each fxx has True/False result, and the termination conditions is all element "True" for one of the combo.
i.e, if fxx's result is True then collect, else goto another fxx.

and If all fxx has already traverse and I can't collect that meet one of the combo, then I can return "Not Found"

Comment: Although I didn't quiet understand the question which you have asked, I think this sounds more like a graph problem which can be solved by various graph traversal algorithms, like dijkstra's algorithm

Comment: I have no idea exactly what you're traversing (how do you know that f01->f02->f04->f07 is a valid traversal?), but if it's a general graph, it looks to me like you could reduce TSP to this problem quite easily.

Comment: Sorry maybe I am not a good story teller. 
Since each fxx is a True/False result, so I think there are more like decision tree concept.
I have surveyed the general graph algorithm, I don't the if it suitable or how can I transfer my question into.